# Проблема с относительным импортом в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, модули

Вот структура файла:

```
modules
|-__init__.py
|-folder_swicher_user_agent
  |-__init__.py
  |-swicher_user_agent_v1.py
|-log_functions
  |-__init__.py
  |-create_one_error_log_f.py
```

Верхний **init**.py

```
from .folder_swicher_user_agent import *
from .log_functions import *

__all__ = ['folder_swicher_user_agent', 'log_functions']
```

Первый **init**.py

```
from .swicher_user_agent_v1 import *

__all__ = ['swicher_user_agent_v1']
```

Второй **init**.py

```
from .create_one_error_log_f import *

__all__ = ['create_one_error_log_f']
```

файл swicher

```
from ..log_functions.create_one_error_log_f import *
create_error_one_log('Привет')
```

файл error

```
import os
import datetime


def create_error_one_log(text_for_type_of_error):
    now_time_in_function_create_error_one_log = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('Время: %H:%M:%S')
    now_date_in_function_create_error_one_log = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('Дата: %d.%m.%Y')
    way_to_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'tables_user_agent', 'table_user_agent_1.txt')
    ready_message_in_error_log = f'\n\n{now_date_in_function_create_error_one_log}\n{now_time_in_function_create_error_one_log}\nПуть к файлу: {way_to_file}\nТип ошибки:{text_for_type_of_error}'
    with open('test_log_2.txt', 'a') as log_now:
        log_now.write(ready_message_in_error_log)
```

Пробема в том, что при запуске swicher выдается ошибка - attempted relative import with no known parent package - как ее решить?

Comment: В Python невозможен импорт модуля, для получения доступа к которому нужно возвращаться на уровень выше. Вы можете импортировать только те модули, которые находятся на одном уровне с текущим либо ниже него. В вашем же случае необходимо вернуться на уровень выше (в корневую директорию) и перейти оттуда в `log_functions`

Comment: Ааа, понятно, а тогда вопрос - а как тогда это реализовать?